# Dynamic SQl with stored proc

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

How can I use sp_executesql with dynamic value parameters

I want to generate the parameter value by a loop from a comma separated string or something like this

```
declare @sql nvarchar(1000),  @answer nvarchar(1000)
set @sql='SELECT TOP 1000 [UserID]
      ,[DateOfBirth]
      ,[UserActivityType]
      ,[FirstName]
      ,[LastName]
      ,[Gender]
  FROM [LogX].[dbo].[UserDetails] where firstname=@name and gender =@gender '
  set @values =  '"jack","1"' 
  EXEC  sp_executesql   @sql  , N'@name nvarchar(100),@gender tinyint',@values
```

please be aware that there can be more than 2 parameters
Any Idea?
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
declare @sql nvarchar(1000),  @answer nvarchar(1000)
set @sql='SELECT TOP 1000 [UserID]
      ,[DateOfBirth]
      ,[UserActivityType]
      ,[FirstName]
      ,[LastName]
      ,[Gender]
  FROM [LogX].[dbo].[UserDetails] where firstname='+@name+' and gender ='+@gender
  set @values =  '"jack","1"' 
  EXEC  sp_executesql   @sql  , N'@name nvarchar(100),@gender tinyint',@values
```

use string concatination for passing parameters

Comment: What about `@name = '; drop tables; --`  I won't downvote because it's a valid answer to the question though, but this is a baddddd idea IMO

Comment: Thanks Spence yeah thats a really big mistake

Answer (score 0):

You are aware that the ENTIRE point of sp_executesql is to prevent you doing string concatenation.  You can use a library such as linq to dynamically generate queries for you which will then use sp_Executesql.

String concatenation in SQL queries is a key attack vector against websites and applications called SQL Injection.  [SQL Injection at wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

Answer (score 0):

You would need to parse the CSV string of values out into distinct variables to then pass to sp_executesql - there's no way round that when doing parameterised SQL as you are (which is exactly what you should be doing).

Otherwise, you'd be looking at doing (horrible) string concatenation for your dynamic SQL instead of parameterising which would be bad.

Comment: Can you please tell me how? I mean How can i create multiple parameters on the fly ? cos there meight be 1 or 10 of them you know its a dynamic one 
Many thanks.